# Unable scrape certain fields from a given string using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to parse `weight`, `depth` and `height` from the following string using regex `'84" w x 39" d x 37" h'`. I got success while scooping out `weight` and `depth` for it. However, I could not scrape the `height` in the right way. I know the patterns I've used might be very weak but it works for the first two fields.

I've tried with:

```
import re

rstr = '84" w x 39" d x 37" h'

weight = re.findall(r"(.*?)\"\s*?w",rstr)[0]
depth = re.findall(r"x\s*(.*?)\"\s*?d",rstr)[0]
height = re.findall(r"x\s*(.*?)\"\s*?h",rstr)[0]
print(weight,depth,height)
```

Output I'm getting:

```
84 39 39" d x 37
```

Output I wish to get:

```
84 39 37
```

The weight, depth and height may not always be in the same order.

> How can I scrape the three fields from the above string using regex?

Comment: You should match digits explicitly, do not use `.`. `x\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)"?\s*h`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/Rcvk9w/1/).

Comment: Or like `\b(\d+)" \w x (\d+)" d x (\d+)" h\b` https://regex101.com/r/02EQNV/1 to get all of them in a single pattern and then use the groups

Comment: Thanks a lot @Wiktor Stribiżew for your suggested pattern. It works perfectly.

Comment: Your pattern also works @The fourth bird. But, I wish to get them separately using individual pattern. Thanks.

Comment: @SMTH You can https://ideone.com/9QDhei

Answer (score 1, accepted):

w, d, and h are not in same order, which makes one-line find all a bit hard, but probably still doable.

But for now, let us stick with one line for each:

```
re.findall(r'\d+(?=" w)',string)[0]
re.findall(r'\d+(?=" d)',string)[0]
re.findall(r'\d+(?=" h)',string)[0]
```

Here I also assumed you have integer number, and number of digits could vary. Basically what you really need IMO is a lookahead, a positive lookahead, which is `(?=" d)` in the search pattern.

By the way, the above matches are str right now, you may need int() it if any calculation is needed down the road.